# Angular : Make class available for an entire module

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I have a simple class file `language.ts` like this :

```
export class Language {
    constructor(
        public code: string,
        public libelle: string) {}
}
```

I have only one module

How to make this class available for an **entire module** ?

EDIT --

Thanks [@JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), I understand that it's really not a best practise to put it globally. I need to import it in **each file**.
But if i want to have global value, like this for example :

```
    export class Language {

        languages = [
            new Language("fr", "Français"),
            new Language("en", "Anglais")
          ];
        currentLanguage = this.languages[0];

        constructor(
            public code: string,
            public libelle: string) {}
}
```

How can I acess those values in components ?

Comment: its just a class. just import it wherever you want to use it.

Comment: yes, but i wonder if there is a way to avoid to import it in each class of my components where i want to use it

Comment: @marojbor the whole point of using JS/TS modules is to avoid such horrible global types, which cause clashes, and which can't be bundled efficiently. Use a good IDE, which adds the necessary imports automatically. If you type the imports by hand, you need to improve your tooling.

Comment: If you want it to be available to every component, then see my answer.

Comment: @Sarah-1 Your answer is wrong.

Comment: @marojbor Your code doesn't make much sense, since calling its constructor calls itself recursicely. But if you want a value to be available globally, then you can simply export a `const someValue = ...`, and import it wherever you want it, or use an Angular service containing this value and inject it in every component which needs it.

Answer (score -2):

If you just want to use the class in a module, just import it and it will be available.

However, by the wording “make it available to entire module” sounds like you mean “to make it available to “ the entire APP? If so see below.

Add it to the providers array of the **app.module**.ts located in

```
src/app/app.module.ts
```

First, import your class in that file like

```
import { Language } from './language ';
```

Next add it to the Providers array like this:

```
providers: [
YourClass,
```

/* . . . */
  ],

Comment: This makes no sense. The class the OP posted is not a service. It has nothing to do in a module providers.

Comment: Op says make it available for the entire module which sounds like entire APP

Comment: Yes. And Simply importing the class wherever you want to use it is all you need to do that.